# How return a basic className for element which was not clicked React

Tags: reactjs

I have a category menu that changes the style when you click on the category, how  change the handle, so that the style is automatically reset  for another category?

```
class CategoryOfMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { itemmenu: this.props.data[0] };
  }

  handleClick(id, e) {
    this.setState({ itemmenu: this.props.data[id] });
    console.log(this.props.data[id].categorymenu);
    if (e.target.className === 'liik1') {
      e.target.className = 'liik';
    } else {
      e.target.className = 'liik1';
    }
  }

  render() {
    var categoryMenu = this.props.data.map(function(data, id) {
      return (
        <li key={id} data={data} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, id)}>
          {' '}{data.categorymenu}{' '}
        </li>
      );
    }, this);

    return (
      <div className="pic">
        <div className="menu">
          <h3>Menu</h3>
          <ul>
            {categoryMenu}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <ItemOfMenu data={this.state.itemmenu} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, there are two ways to do it.

The first is to create another prop in your state which indicates the selected item.

The second is to flush all selected states and set the new one.

Here is the first method.

```js
class Menu extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: ['first', 'second', 'third'],
    selected: 0,
  }
  
  getClassName (index) {
    const defaultClass = 'menuItem';
    
    if (index === this.state.selected) {
      return `${defaultClass} isSelected`;
    }
    
    return defaultClass;
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
          <li 
            key={item} 
            className={this.getClassName(index)} 
            onClick={() => this.setState({selected: index})}
          >
            {item}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Menu />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menuItem {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.isSelected {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```